# Lda on Bi(multi)lingual Corpus

Tags: lda, topic-modeling, gensim

I'm trying to reproduce the results of Graber et al. in showing that when LDA is used with a multilingual corpus, the most probable terms for a topic (say, top 10) will come from a single language. Their paper is [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.2657.pdf).

This is a reasonable sanity check to perform IMO, but I'm having difficulty.

I'm using the same corpus they used, the [Europarl corpus](http://www.statmt.org/europarl/), with the corpus composed of Bulgarian and English.  I concatenated the Bulgarian and English corpuses with

```
cat corpusBg.txt corpusEn.txt >> corpusMixed.txt.
```

This contains a sentence on each line, with the collection of lines in Bulgarian and the second collection in English. When I fit an LDA model with 4 topics, 3 contain only English terms in the top 10, and the fourth is mixed between English and Bulgarian. I'm using the default settings for LDA:

```
texts = [[word for word in doc.lower().split()] for doc in open('corpusMixed.txt', 'r')]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in texts]
lda = models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, id2word = dictionary, num_topics = 4)
topics = lda.print_topics(lda.num_topics)

for t in topics:
    print t
```

Note that I have not removed stopwords or sparse terms, but I think that this shouldn't matter. There should intuitively be some topics with terms only in bulgarian and others with terms only in English, no?

Answer (score 0):

In the paper, they use a 10 topic model to discuss the phenomenon. You're using only 4.

When you run LDA with a small number of topics, distinct semantic topics get merged into 'chimera' topics ([David Mimno's term](http://journalofdigitalhumanities.org/2-1/the-details-by-david-mimno/), I believe). With only 4 topics for a corpus with "around 60 million words per language" that would be almost inevitable. To be honest, I'm surprised that 10 topics is enough, though I guess LDA would find it hard to merge topics from different languages, as very few word pairs from different languages would appear together in sentences.

Comment: That's a good point about the paper. I had overlooked that detail in the figure caption. I refit with 10 topics, and now all of my topics contain only English words.

Regardless, I watched the video, and I have noted the "Chimera topics" phenomenon.  My intuition had suggested to me that setting the number of topics was akin to setting a resolution level at which to determine topics.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes, that's more or less correct. However we can think of it like this also: if there are too many real, semantic topics of appropriate resolution, some will end up bundled together. Remember also that it's just an approximation - real text does not follow the assumptions in the model, so strange things can happen! Topics can represent stylistic or habitual language use (ie: not semantic), and things like repeated text snippets can have strange effects.

Comment: Only English words appearing... Are you sure you've both languages present? (a quick look at the vocab should tell you). If the English corpus is significantly larger than the Bulgarian, it's topics will likely dominate the Bulgarian ones.. Perhaps you could just cut it down or add more topics. What pre-processing did you do? Removed stop words? very high/low frequency words? words with bad tf/idf scores? ([Blei](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiLafferty2009.pdf) has such an approach, page 11 or search for 'Choosing the vocabulary')